Convolution of discretized functions
I would like to do the convolution of functions (in the mathematical way) using scipy convolution functions but it appears to give different results from what I expect.
I first define a grid of points:
def generate_square_mesh(num_points=50):
    
    x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, num_points)
    y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, num_points)
    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
    return x_grid, y_grid

I then compute the pairwise matrix of my kernel so that if I multiply it with an other function I should get the convolution of the function with the kernel
def heat_kernel(x, y, t):
    return np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2) / (4 * t))

def compute_convolution_matrix(x_grid, y_grid, t):
    
    x = x_grid.flatten()
    y = y_grid.flatten()
    dx = x_grid[0, 1] - x_grid[0, 0]
    dy = y_grid[1, 0] - y_grid[0, 0]
    X = x[:, np.newaxis] - x[np.newaxis, :]
    Y = y[:, np.newaxis] - y[np.newaxis, :]
    
    H = heat_kernel(X, Y, t)*dx*dy

    return H

However
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np

x_grid, y_grid = generate_square_mesh(10)
dx = x_grid[0, 1] - x_grid[0, 0]
dy = y_grid[1, 0] - y_grid[0, 0]
t = 0.01
heat_matrix = compute_convolution_matrix(x_grid, y_grid, t)
kernel = heat_kernel(x_grid, y_grid, t)
u0 = np.zeros((10,10))
u0[5,5]=1
A = heat_matrix@u0.flatten()
B = convolve2d(u0, kernel, mode='same')*dx*dy

I get different results for Aand B. I would have expected the two to be the same.
It appears that the results kind of have the same shape in the same area of the grid but the values are different.

What are your values of dx and dy for the last line (B = convolve2d(u0, kernel, mode='same')*dx*dy)? At present, with the code that you share, they are undefined. Also, as a side node, the import numpy as np import is missing.

Oh sorry I'll correct the post, it's just the size of the spatial discretization

I did not dig too deep, but what I found: In compute_convolution_matrix(), if you print print("X", sorted(np.unique(np.round(X, decimals=3)).tolist())), you will get X [-1.0, -0.889, -0.778, -0.667, -0.556, -0.444, -0.333, -0.222, -0.111, 0.0, 0.111, 0.222, 0.333, 0.444, 0.556, 0.667, 0.778, 0.889, 1.0]. Thus, here you sample x_kernel on an odd number of values spanning from -1 to 1. If you create the kernel via heat_kernel(x_grid, y_grid, t), however, you sample on an even number of values (namely, 10) spanning from -0.5 to 0.5.

This would explain already why the result of your convolution in the first case has a peak of exactly one pixel (as the largest kernel value is unique there), while in the second case the peak in your result is a plateau of 2×2 pixels (as the largest kernel value spans 2 pixels there). Not sure if this helps you and not sure what you would need to do for fixing.

Note that you create X from x_grid essentially by X = x_grid.flatten()[:, np.newaxis] - x_grid.flatten()[np.newaxis, :]. The subtraction of the broadcasted values in x_grid with themselves implies both; namely (1) that X spans double the range of values of x_grid and (2) that X holds 2n-1 (an odd number) of different values while x_grid holds n (in your case 10, i.e. an even number of) different values.

Oops, in my comment above, x_kernel should be heat kernel (called H in the code), of course.

Well the thing is that as I diffuse a dirac in one point I would expect the result of the convolution to give a plateau of just one pixel (the point of the dirac) but I see you're point

Indeed you diffuse a single point, but in the latter case (heat_kernel(x_grid, y_grid, t)) with a kernel that has a two-pixel plateau. The center of the kernel (kernel[3:7, 3:7], without multiplying dx, dy) there looks as follows: [[0.249 0.462 0.462 0.249] [0.462 0.857 0.857 0.462] [0.462 0.857 0.857 0.462] [0.249 0.462 0.462 0.249]]. Note how you have the highest value, 0.857, four times (or rather 2×2 times). Of course, your convolution of a single point will then also have a 2×2 plateau.

Would one way to solve the problem be to have a grid with alway and odd number of points ? like (11,11) instead of (10,10) ?

Indeed, that seems to do the trick. If I use (11, 11) everywhere, I get exactly the same values in both A.reshape(11, 11) and B. I kicked out dx, dy in your code, but that shouldn't make a difference.
